# How do i detect multiple languages on the same line?

Tags: java, python, language-detection

There are a couple of api's in java as well as python and also tried some online demos but all the api's takes the sentence as a whole and give an overall probable language. In my case, i have multiple languages on the same line that needs to be detected and languages except English is to be eliminated while keeping in meaning of the sentences intact.

Examples:

1. Safe for septic tanks. / Sans danger pour les fosses septiques.  Store in a cool, dry place. / Ranger dans un endroit frais et sec.
2. 4X CONCENTRATED TO CLEAN BETTER*  4X PLUS CONCENTRÉ POUR MIEUX NETTOYER*
3. PHOSPHATE FREE  SANS PHOSPHATE
4. Imported for / Importé pour  PROCTER & GAMBLE INC., TORONTO, ON M5W 1C5

Comment: Is this template that your are reading from a constant ?? if it is then you can scrape the parts you need using regular expressions and prepare a only English template dynamically.

Comment: also do add code excerpts of what you have tried and mention which libraries you have used.

Comment: @praveen the input is not constant. it is pdfs that is being read by pdfbox. the text have multiple languages.

Comment: This breaks down very quickly once you remember that English has borrowed many, many foreign words and phrases wholesale, so it will be difficult to tell if a particular word is foreign or an English borrowing.  Unless there's a specific arrangement or meta-syntax you can use to identify the foreign parts any code you write will probably be wrong about 25% of the time.

Comment: Using your example, what if number 3 had the French first: "Sans Phosphate Phosphate Free".   Which "Phosphate" is English?  Are both English, or they both French?  In example 1 you have French and English _interleaved_, so how to you know the word TORONTO in #4 doesn't represent a switch back to English. For that matter, how do you know "PROCTER & GAMBLE" isn't a swirch back to English?  Good luck/

Comment: i have tried -tokenizing the entire sentence into words and checking language for each words, but they leave the meaning jumbled

Comment: thats the problem i am basically facing and am clueless on how to solve that @jim

Comment: My point is that this task is not possible unless you can accept a 25% error rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the direction you have taken from reading the comments is the best solution : "i have tried -tokenizing the entire sentence into words and checking language for each words". However you should consider developing a [bag of words algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model).

simply put you would count occurrences of all words in the sentence and store them in a list with a index of which language they belong too. 
However as you are detecting multiple languages in a single sentence which may share words you would require multiple lists, the list which has the most occurrences of the languages word(s) would determine the language of each part of the sentence.

```
This is an English sentence written in english,dans un endroit frais et sec
[english:english:2][this:english:1][is:english:1][an:english:1][sentence:english:1][written:english:1][in:english:1]
[dans:french:1][un:french:1][endroit:french:1][et:french:1][sec:french:1]

this->beginning->list index 0, sentence->end of english->list index 3
```

However this still may produce errors in your examples as the smaller the sample space is the more inaccurate the result:

Safe for septic tanks. / Sans danger pour les fosses septiques. Store in a cool, dry place. / Ranger dans un endroit frais et sec. (**All words occur only once which wont help determine language by count of words, only by sum of which language they consecutively belong to**)

Anyway hope this kind of makes sense and hope it helps in someway for you to find a solution. Feel free to comment and I will try to help you with your questions.